# How to support different resolutions in titanium Alloy XML

Tags: ios, iphone, titanium, titanium-alloy

I am using Titanium Alloy framework , the issue is I have set the sizing parameters according to iphone 5. When I compile for iphone 4, there comes some kind of disturbance in UI.

In short, I want the way to handle different screen resolutions in iphone both 4 and 5 in the `.tss` and `.xml` files in Titanium Alloy.

Answer (score 1):

you can try to set condition according to the below link.

http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/159770/do-we-have-any-conditions-to-handle-in-xml-file#comment-195451

in that instead of Alloy.Globals.isIOS7, you can use your own boollean global variable to check whether its iphone 4 or 5.

Answer (score 0):

@Mitul Bhalia is correct.

1.detect the specific screen resolution:

```
// app/alloy.js
Alloy.Globals.isIos7Plus = (OS_IOS && parseInt(Ti.Platform.version.split(".")[0]) >= 7);
Alloy.Globals.iPhoneTall = (OS_IOS && Ti.Platform.osname == "iphone" && Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight == 568);
```

2.write query style tss:

```
// Query styles
"#info[if=Alloy.Globals.isIos7Plus]" : {
    font : { textStyle : Ti.UI.TEXT_STYLE_FOOTNOTE }
},
"#title[if=Alloy.Globals.isIos7Plus]" : {
    top: '25dp', // compensate for the status bar on iOS 7
    font : { textStyle : Ti.UI.TEXT_STYLE_HEADLINE }
},
"#content[if=Alloy.Globals.isIos7Plus]" : {
    font : { textStyle : Ti.UI.TEXT_STYLE_CAPTION1 }
},
"ScrollView[if=Alloy.Globals.iPhoneTall]" : {
    height : '500dp'
}
```

refer to:  http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Alloy_Styles_and_Themes-section-35621526_AlloyStylesandThemes-Platform-SpecificStyles

see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28298508/445908