# How to style titanium / alloy controls

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-alloy

To be specific, I'd like to know how to make elements have same dimensions on different devices. For example:

**tiapp.xml**

```
<property name="ti.ui.defaultunit" type="string">dp</property>
```

**index.tss**

```
".box": {
    width: 210,
    height: 210,
    top: 20,
    left: 20
}
```

Dimensions and margins in the box class are in pixels - I didn't recalculate them to dps, because I don't know how. I know I should use this equation `pixels / (Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.dpi / 160)` but since I can't do it in my tss file, then what options do I have? How do I make this element display the same way on a device with 480x800 screen and 720x1280 screen?

Comment: well i mostly use `<property name="ti.ui.defaultunit" type="string">px</property>` and define **font-size** in **sp**

Comment: Using pixels is not a good solution. I would have to recalculate my element size for each possible resolution...

Comment: ah sorry got confused we should use **dp** for android. you can check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326632/titanium-handling-different-resoutions) question for more help.